# Optimizing big import in php

Tags: php, micro-optimization

I have a simple importer, it goes through each line of a rather big csv and imports it to the database.

My question is: Should I call another method to insert each object (generating a DO and telling it's mapper to insert) or should I hardcode the insert process in the import method, duplicating the code?

I know the elegant thing to do is to call the second method, but I keep hearing in my head that function calls are expensive.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many RDBMS brands support a special command to do bulk imports.  For example:

- MySQL: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
- PostgreSQL: [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)
- Microsoft SQL Server: [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)
- Oracle: [`SQL*Loader`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ)

Using these commands is preferred over inserting one row at a time from a CSV data source because the bulk-loading command usually runs at least an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't even think of that :-D

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this matters too much. Consider a bulk insert. At least make sure you're using a transaction, and consider to disable indices before inserting.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter, as the insertion will take probably orders of magnitude longer than the php code.

As others have stated, bulk insert will give you much more benefit.
Those line-level optimizations will only make you blind for the good higher level optimizations.

If you are unsure, do a simple timing with both ways, it shouldn't take longer than a couple of minutes to find out.

Consider combining both approaches to make batch inserts, if all-at-once hits some memory/time/.... limits.