# PHP or C# script to parse CSV table values to fill in one-to-many table

Tags: c#, php, database, parsing, one-to-many

I'm looking for an example of how to split-out comma-delimited data in a field of one table, and fill in a second table with those individual elements, in order to make a one-to-many relational database schema. This is probably really simple, but let me give an example:

I'll start with everything in one table, *Widgets*, which has a "state" field to contain states that have that widget:

**Table: WIDGET**

```
===============================
| id | unit | states          |
===============================
|1   | abc  | AL,AK,CA        |
-------------------------------
|2   | lmn  | VA,NC,SC,GA,FL  |
-------------------------------
|3   | xyz  | KY              |
===============================
```

Now, what I'd like to create via code is a second table to be joined to WIDGET called *Widget_ST* that has widget id, widget state id, and widget state name fields, for example

**Table: WIDGET_ST**

```
==============================
| w_id | w_st_id | w_st_name |
------------------------------
|1     | 1       | AL        |
|1     | 2       | AK        |
|1     | 3       | CA        |
|2     | 1       | VA        |
|2     | 2       | NC        |
|2     | 1       | SC        |
|2     | 2       | GA        |
|2     | 1       | FL        |
|3     | 1       | KY        |
==============================
```

I am learning C# and PHP, so responses in either language would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote some scripts to import the Stack Overflow data dump into an SQL database.  I split the *tags* list to populate a many-to-many table as you describe.  I use a technique similar to the following:

1. Read a row from WIDGET

   ```
   while ($row = $pdoStmt->fetch()) {
   ```
2. Use `explode()` to split on a comma

   ```
   $states = explode(",", $row["state"]);
   ```
3. Loop over elements, writing to a new CSV file

   ```
   $stateid = array();
   $stfile = fopen("states.csv", "w+");
   $mmfile = fopen("manytomany.csv", "w+");
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($state as $st) {
       if (!array_key_exists($st, $stateid)) {
           $stateid[$st] = ++$i;
           fprintf($stfile, "%d,%s\n", $i, $st);
       }
       fprintf($mmfile, "%s,%s\n", $row["id"], $stateid[$st]);
   }
   fclose($stfile);
   fclose($mmfile);
   ```
4. When you're done, load the CSV files into the database.  You can do this in the mysql client:

   ```
   mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'states.csv' INTO TABLE STATES;
   mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'manytomany.csv' INTO TABLE WIDGET_ST;
   ```

It may seem like a lot of work, but using the LOAD DATA command runs 20x faster than inserting one row at a time, so it's worthwhile if your data set is large.

---

Re your comment:

Right, I also have data in a database already.  It turns out that the solution I show above, dumping to CSV files and re-importing in normalized format, is **many times faster** than doing INSERT statements inside the loop that splits the data.

Each brand of database has its own tool for importing bulk data.  See my answer to [Optimizing big import in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970504/optimizing-big-import-in-php/2970519#2970519) for a list of bulk import solutions per database.

You should use the tools provided by each database.  Trying to remain cross platform only makes your code [Jack of all trades, master of none](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_all_trades,_master_of_none).  Besides, in 90% of cases when people bend over backwards to make their code database-independent, it turns out they never use more than one database.  And you can't achieve complete database independence anyway.

Comment: I'll give you a point - but I'm also looking for something that's more "cross platform", since my DBMS might be SQL Server 2008, or postgres, etc. I also already have the original table in a database format, and I'm trying to update it by making use of more relations as needed. Thanks all the same